# Bash script to update BIND ACL - unwanted character

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I am trying to update a file on a server where the new line needs to have a single tab at the front but new to bash scripting and sed and keep getting an unwanted character at the front.

This is the sed command:

```
sed -i "/acl \"trusted\" {/a&\t$ACL_IP;    # $SRV_HOST_NAME" $ACL_CONF_FILE

In the results I get :
&       192.12.12.12;    # SERVER
        192.13.13.13;    # SERVER1
        192.14.14.14;    # SERVER2

Instead of :
       192.12.12.12;    # SERVER
       192.13.13.13;    # SERVER1
       192.14.14.14;    # SERVER2
```

I also tried the following but get an unknown command error:

```
sed -i "/acl \"trusted\" {/$ACL_IP    # $SRV_HOST_NAME;\r\n\tacl \"trusted\" {/" $ACL_CONF_FILE
```

I have tried also:

```
sed -i "/acl \"trusted\" {/a/\t$ACL_IP;    # $SRV_HOST_NAME" $ACL_CONF_FILE
```

But get:

```
/       192.12.12.12;    # SERVER
```

hoping I am close but just can't see to get rid of the extra character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you are trying to use the (GNU extension) `a text` command to **a**ppend `text` after a match. However, your `text` in this case starts with a tab character, represented in `sed` by the escape sequence `\t`.

Unfortunately there is also a (POSIX compliant) form of the **a**ppend command in which a backslash character separates the `a` command from the `text`. So when you write `a\t` it appends a *literal* `t`. You "fixed" that by placing an additional character (first `&`, then later `/`) to separate the backslash from the `a` command - but that just caused those characters to be appended literally.

To resolve the ambiguity, you need to pass the command as `a\\t`. Unfortunately, because you are using double quotes around the whole sed expression (to allow for expansion of shell variables), the shell will expand `\\` to `\`; to pass `\\` you need to escape both backslashes:

```
sed "/acl \"trusted\" {/a\\\\t$ACL_IP;    # $SRV_HOST_NAME"
```

Alternatively, single-quote the parts that don't need shell expansion:

```
sed '/acl "trusted" {/a\\t'"$ACL_IP;    # $SRV_HOST_NAME"
```

Another option is to replace the escape sequence `\t` by a literal tab, composed using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>TAB</kbd>. You must still use the `a\` form of the command, since the GNU extension `a text` form ignores leading whitespace.

---

Alternatively (and perhaps more cleanly) you could use the `r` command to read a `printf`-formatted string from standard input:

```
printf '\t%s;    # %s\n' "$ACL_IP" "$SRV_HOST_NAME" |
  sed -i '/acl "trusted" {/r/dev/stdin' "$ACL_CONF_FILE"
```

Comment: Thanks steeldriver. that is an excellent explanation and makes perfect sense, many thanks.

Comment: @freddy2020 you're welcome - I've added another alternative that avoids escaping/quoting issues of the `a` command altogether

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver. I am going to have a look at the printf command.

Comment: New to bash scripting and only book I have far is full of mistakes and that is where I got it from but want to learn how to write better code if mine wasn't good?

Comment: @freddy2020 I wouldn't call it *bad* - you just ran across a tricky edge case (using an ANSI escape sequence in a context where the backslash character has another interpretation). For bash itself, my recommended resource is this [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide). For sed I find [Sed One-Liners Explained](https://catonmat.net/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one) useful although I'm not sure it covers your particular use-case.

Comment: Thanks for the links.